# sbt: java.io.IOException: Input/output error

Tags: sbt

on one server I can not launch sbt anymore, it worked well a few months ago. I tried different sbt versions, all new installed: 0.12.1, 0.12.4, 0.13.1. I tried it on a new minimal project, on old projects that worked, different users, always the same IOException (example with sbt 0.13.1). I have [strace output](http://tny.cz/c74d37cd) from 0.12.1. play! 2.1.0 works without problems, I can create new projects, compile them etc...

```
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
Scala code runner version 2.10.1 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL
```

> Loading
>   /groups/csf-ngs/bin/lib/sbt.dir/sbt-0.13.1/bin/sbt-launch-lib.bash
>   java.io.IOException: Input/output error   at
>   sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.lock0(Native Method)    at
>   sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.lock(FileDispatcherImpl.java:89)    at
>   sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.tryLock(FileChannelImpl.java:1024)     at
>   java.nio.channels.FileChannel.tryLock(FileChannel.java:1154)  at
>   xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:88)  at
>   xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:81)
>     at
>   xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:102)
>     at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:11)    at
>   xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:10)    at
>   xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:62)    at
>   xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:52)   at
>   xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)   at
>   xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)    at
>   xsbt.boot.Launch.locked(Launch.scala:178)     at
>   xsbt.boot.Launch.app(Launch.scala:93)     at
>   xsbt.boot.Launch.app(Launch.scala:91)     at
>   xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:51)    at
>   xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$explicit$1.apply(Launch.scala:45)   at
>   xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:65)     at
>   xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:16)  at
>   xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:32)    at
>   xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:21)   at
>   xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala) Error during sbt execution:
>   java.io.IOException: Input/output error

Comment: Did you use the `-f` option with `strace`?

Comment: I updated the link with strace -f (not pastebin anymore because its really long now).

Comment: This was I think due to a NFS/NAS problem. Other programs also failed with IO exceptions on this volume

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mv ~/.sbt ~/.sbt.old
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not help